# Hyper Link That Opens .OFT in Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, execute, oft

I have some Outlook .oft template files uploaded to a web server.

Is it possible to create a link to the individual files that will result in them opening in outlook?

I have thus far only managed to create straight up HTML links that simply downloads them to folder.

Is it possible to create a link that associates the .oft file with outlook and therefore executes it and opens it as the email ready to send.

Thanks

Comment: There is no general way to tell a web browser to open an application to handle a downloaded file (for security reasons), and a bit of googling doesn't show any special method in Outlook to allow this.

Comment: Yeah, I put some Google time into it myself. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the problem - if Outlook is installed, it associates .OFT files with itself. If a link points to an OFT file, opening the file will launch Outlook.

If you mean to bypass the Save/Open prompt in a browser, I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. (Bypass) Thanks for the reply, I feared as much.

Answer (score -1):

When you click the link and it shows the download right click and say always open this kind of file then click to open. After that everytime someone clicks the link it will just open up.